# does the "um" in "um zu" trigger the accusative case?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

If I was writing a text for a company trying to recruit employees, which of the sentences would be grammatically correct? I'm asking here because I'm confused as to whether the word "um" in the phrase "um zu" behaves like a preposition causing the ending of the following words to change.

"Kommen Sie zu uns um deinen Weg zu gestalten" or "Kommen Sie zu uns um dein Weg zu gestalten"

Comment: not your proof reading.

Answer (score 7):

The former is correct (apart from a missing comma before "um"). "Deinen Weg" isn't accusative because of "um", though, it's simply the (accusative) object of "gestalten". You could just as well have something like "damit wir deinen Weg gestalten".

(Having "Sie" in the first part of the sentence and "du" in the second sounds very odd, by the way.)

Answer (score 1):

It does not. Here is an example negative:

> Ich komme, um **dir** zu helfen.

In this case, the verb governs dative and thus the pronoun is dative. An example with accusative that retains the first part would be:

> Ich komme, um **dich** zu unterstüzen.